# avoid package dependency

Tags: android

i have couple of appz(diffrent apk's), and i run activities from one app to another.
my target is to avoid package depndency between them, in case in the future i want to upgrade or compile one package without the absence of another.

the problem is that: without setting the dependecy between eachother(eclipse: buildpath->projects), i cant fire the intents, i`am getting error:"Unable to start activity component..."

any idea how can i solve this issue?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1):

Let A depends on B: `A => B`.

I suggest:

1. to *create a third one package* (named `C`), and move to it shared code.
2. Make dependency `A => C,` and `B => C`.

Now `A` and `B` packages are independent, but they depends on a common package `C`.

Comment: Not sure if is it possible to use external packages on android. Suppose my idea helps you.

Comment: it is possible to use external packages (libraries?) as long as those don't contain any resource files

Comment: so i cant run intent from external package without disable it's dependency?

Comment: I can't understand your question